# How to open original page after google oauth login using django social_auth

Tags: python, django, oauth

I'm using django social_auth for user identification and it works great when user first login. However, if access token expired or directly open page by url, user will be redirect to a default page ('/') after google oauth. What should I do to get original page after google oauth login?

Here is my settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django_extensions',    
'bootstrap3',
'djangobower',
'social_auth',
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social_auth.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2Backend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = 'CLIENT_ID'
GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = 'CLIENT_SECRET'
SOCIAL_AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'auth.User'
SESSION_SERIALIZER='django.contrib.sessions.serializers.PickleSerializer'
GOOGLE_WHITE_LISTED_DOMAINS = ['google.com']

SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_AUTH_EXTRA_ARGUMENTS = {
    'access_type': 'offline',
    'approval_prompt': 'select_account+consent',
    'prompt' : 'select_account+consent'
}
```

login.html:

```
{% load bootstrap3 %}
{% load static %}
<link media="all" href="{% static 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src='{% static 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}'></script>
{% load static %}    
<script type="text/javascript" src='{% static 'jquery/jquery.js' %}'></script>
<link media="all" href="{% static 'dashboard.css' %}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src='{% static 'canvasjs/canvasjs.min.js' %}' type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'signin.css' %}" /> 

{% if form.errors %}
<p text-align="center">Your username and password didn't match. Please try again. {{form.errors}} </p>
{% endif %}

<form method="post" action="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}" class="form-signin" role="form">
{% csrf_token %}
<h2 class="form-signin-heading">ABC Website</h2>
<input id="id_username" maxlength="254" name="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" autofocus/>
<input id="id_password" name="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"/>
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">System Account LogIn</button>
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
</form>

<p style="text-align: center"><a href="{% url "socialauth_begin" "google-oauth2" %}?prompt=select_account+consent">GMail Login</a></p>
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
url(r'^accounts/logout/$', login_required(views.logout_view), name = "logout"),    
url(r'^complete/(?P<backend>[^/]+)/$', views.AuthComplete.as_view()),
url(r'^login-error/$', views.LoginError.as_view(), 'login-error'),
url(r'', include('social_auth.urls')),    
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

Comment: what do you mean original page?

Comment: Means user already login the website but have to relogin due to access token expired, or open url directly. So original page is the user requested page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your html template you could have this within your login button to redirect to the same page:

```
href="{% url 'social:begin' 'google-oauth2' %}?next={{ request.path }}"
```

"next=" specifies where to link to next after logging in. So "next={{ request.path }}" links to the same path as the original request.

If you're just redirecting to the homepage then just use "next=/":

```
href="{% url 'social:begin' 'google-oauth2' %}?next=/"
```

Comment: I try href="{% url 'social:begin' 'google-oauth2' %}?next={{ request.path }} this morning, but failed to login. It always redirect to login page. Originally I use <a href="{% url "socialauth_begin" "google-oauth2" %}?prompt=select_account+consent"> for login button, if I append ?next={{ request.path }}, it will get 404 error.

Comment: I found {{ request.path }} always get "/accounts/login"... How did I do to fix that?

Comment: I was unsure what pages you were switching between. {{ request.path }} gives you the url of the request (I guess your login page. So, use "next=/" to redirect to your homepage

Comment: After try & error I found the root cause is login_required(). It will redirect user to /accounts/login & append a query string ?next=/url/youwant/, so {{ request.path }} only get url "/accounts/login" and drop the query string. My solution is use href="{% url 'social:begin' 'google-oauth2' %}?{{ request.META.QUERY_STRING }}" to get the information I want.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the right direction to final solution :)

Comment: Django official documents about request & responds object [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict)

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is to override `get_context_data` function
In the CBV do:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    next_page = self.request.GET.get('next')
    context['next'] = next_page
    return context
```

Then in the template:

```
href="{% url 'social:begin' 'google-oauth2' %}?next={{ next }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `settings.py` file:

```py
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/"
```

Comment: Hey! Can you add a little bit of explanation to this? Would be great to new folks to know what the issue was and why this will fix it.